# How to pass a query to render_template as a json format?

Tags: python, json, flask-sqlalchemy

It's been a while I am trying to represent a list of dictionaries as a json output.

here is my model.py:

```
class User(db.Model):
    """
        class to create users
    """

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def to_dict(self):
        return dict([(k, getattr(self, k)) for k in self.__dict__.keys() if not k.startswith("_")])
```

and in view.py:

```
@app.route('/user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():

    datas = User.query.all()
    results = []
    for result in datas:
        results.append(result.to_dict())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['Search']
        return redirect((url_for('search_results', query=query)))
    return render_template('search_results.html', results=results)
```

in search.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
     {% for result in results %}
          <li>{{ result }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

*Question:*

My question is that, how to show a list of dictionaries in my html template as a json formate.

I know that with `return jsonify(results)` I can have a route with a list of json formats but how to bring it under something like `return render_template('search_results.html', results=json.dumbs(results))`

*Expectation:*

I expect something like:

```
[
  {'id': 1,
   'username ': JackS,
   'email':'demo@gmail.com'},
  {'id': 2,
   'username ': RossS,
   'email':'x@gmail.com'},
  ....
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `toJSON` method to your `User` model

```
  def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True)
```

Now you can use `json.dumps` to create a JSON string format from the queryset result

```
return render_template('search_results.html', results=json.dumps(results)
```

Comment: I replaced your solution but it slides all every dictionary letter and then prints